# adb locat - cannot redirect to textfile - read only filesystem

Tags: adb, logging

When I trie to show logs of a specific priority in logcat and direct the stream to a textfile I get the following error message:

```
 1|shell@android:/ $ adb logcat "*:W" > logcat.txt                             
 /system/bin/sh: can't create logcat.txt: Read-only file system
```

What has the Read-only file system to do with directing the output to textfile? How do I get around this? probably via

```
chmod +w <file>
```

but which folder/file in the linux-filesystem of my android device?

Are there better get-arounds?

*I can underline that my device is already rooted.*

Comment: adb logcat -v threadtime > <destination on you computer>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`adb logcat` on your phone launches an ADB server on your phone (which is also running on your PC) and connects to itself.

Then you try to write everything to `/logcat.txt` (`/` is the the root of your filesystem; you can't write there).

Try routing your output to something like `/sdcard/logcat.txt` or run it directly on your PC, where it gets saved in the current working directory of your `cmd.exe`.

Comment: Ok, maybe I completely missed something here? I thought it was directed to where I am in the computers filesystem, since **adb logcat > logcat.txt** does that.

Comment: It does that, as long as you run from your computer. `adb shell` runs on your phone.

Answer (score 2):

In your command line example, you are running the ADB command from the Android terminal with `/` as current directory. So Android tries to write the output to `/logcat.txt`, which fails.

Keep in mind that after you execute `adb shell` everything you type happens on the phone. The command `adb logcat` then runs on your phone, and the creation of the text file *also* happens on your phone.

Because `/` is read-only in Android you get the error you described.

If you just want the logcat on your PC, run `adb logcat > logcat.txt` from your PC with your phone connected. If you want to save the logcat on your phone, type `logcat > /sdcard/logcat.txt` to save it to a writable location.